# ReactJs can't fix missing semicolon error before "render()"

Tags: reactjs

I was following ProgrammingWithMosh's reactJs tutorial, and I am now stuck in the App.js file (I have other children components in my project too, but I have not posted their code in this question) due to the following error:

> ';' expected. [Line 41 of the following code]

This error occurs on the line where "render()" is found - right after the "render()" keyword and before its first "{" bracket.

[image: Here is the image of where the error occurs for more clarification]

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import Counters from './components/counters';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 },
    ],
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map((c) => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState({ counters: counters });
  };

  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    // console.log(counter);
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    // counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters: counters });
    // console.log(this.state.counters[index]);
  };

  handleDelete = (counterId) => {
    // console.log("Event Handler Called", counterId);
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter((c) => c.id !== counterId);
    // console.log(counters);
    this.setState({ counters: counters });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar />
        <main className="container">
          <Counters
            counters={this.state.counters}
            onReset={this.handleReset}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
          />
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I cannot figure out what semi colons I am missing and I have also checked to see if I am missing any ending brackets from previous functions (which to my knowledge, I am not). Please help me pinpoint the issue, and thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You're mixing a function component with a class component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing a function component with a class component.

change

```
function App() {
```

to

```
class App extends Component {
```